# Why are only some modeline settings being applied in Vim?

Tags: vim, configuration

I'm editing python files and I have a modeline in one of them as follows:

```
# vim: set foldmarker={{{,}}} foldlevel=0  foldmethod=marker
```

When I open the file, `foldmethod` is still set to `expr`, but the other two settings in the modeline have been successfully applied, and `set modeline?` reveals that `modeline` is indeed set.

I suspect this is happening because a plugin is overriding the setting after the modeline is applied, but how can I check if that's the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your modeline syntax is incorrect. You are setting `foldmarker` and `foldlevel` to the default values, so that's probably why it looks like those settings are being applied. Your modeline should be

```
# vim: set foldmarker={{{,}}} foldlevel=0 foldmethod=marker :
```

Note the `:` at the end of the line, it is required.

There is another syntax for modelines that doesn't require the closing colon but it also cannot have a leading set:

```
# vim: foldmarker={{{,}}} foldlevel=0 foldmethod=marker
```

Either one will work for you. I tend to use the first syntax because the second cannot be used in languages where you need some text at the end of the line to close the comment.

Comment: You can use `:verbose set foldmarker? foldlevel? foldmethod?` to see which options were set from the modeline.

Comment: @benjifisher, that's really useful, thanks. I always forget about `verbose`…